# Check time series incongruencies

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, aggregate

Let's say that we have the following matrix:

```
x<- as.data.frame(cbind(c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D","D"),
                        c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5),
                        c(14,28,42,14,46,64,71,85,14,28,51,84,66,22,38,32,40,42)))
colnames(x)<- c("ID","Visit", "Age")
```

The first column represents subject ID, the second a list of observations and the third the age at each of this consecutive observations.

Which would be the easiest way of finding visits where the age is wrong according to the previous visit age. (i.e. in row 13, subject C is 66 years old, when in the previous visit he was already 84 or in row 16, subject D is 32 years old, when in the previous visit he was already 38).

Which would be the way of highlighting the potential errors and removing rows 13 and 16?

I have tried to aggregate by IDs and look for the difference between ages across visits, but it seems hard for me since the error could occur in any visit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this in base R?

```
df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(split(x, x$ID), function(w) 
    w[c(1, which(diff(w[order(w$Visit), "Age"]) > 0) + 1), ]));
df;
#    ID Visit Age
#A.1   A     1  14
#A.2   A     2  28
#A.3   A     3  42
#B.4   B     1  14
#B.5   B     2  46
#B.6   B     3  64
#B.7   B     4  71
#B.8   B     5  85
#C.9   C     1  14
#C.10  C     2  28
#C.11  C     3  51
#C.12  C     4  84
#D.14  D     1  22
#D.15  D     2  38
#D.17  D     4  40
#D.18  D     5  42
```

Explanation: We split the `dataframe` on column `ID`, then order every `dataframe` subset by `Visit`, calculate differences between successive `Age` values, and only keep those rows where the difference is > 0 (i.e. `Age` is increasing); `rbind`ing gives the final `dataframe`.

Comment: Thank you. This solves this issue, but I have realized that my problem is more complex. I'll ask the question again.

Comment: @Yatrosin No problem. I would suggest accepting/upvoting an answer, and then asking a different question in a separate post (perhaps providing a link to this one to provide context).

Comment: Dear @maurits-evers, I posted the new question last night, but I haven't found an answer for it. Can you please have a look at it? This is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47746656/how-to-remove-inconsistencies-from-dataframe-time-series

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by filtering out the rows where `diff(Age)` is negative for each `ID`. 
Using the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

x %>% group_by(ID) %>%  filter(c(0,diff(Age))>=0)
# A tibble: 16 x 3
# Groups:   ID [4]
       ID  Visit    Age
   <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>
 1      A      1     14
 2      A      2     28
 3      A      3     42
 4      B      1     14
 5      B      2     46
 6      B      3     64
 7      B      4     71
 8      B      5     85
 9      C      1     14
10      C      2     28
11      C      3     51
12      C      4     84
13      D      1     22
14      D      2     38
15      D      4     40
16      D      5     42
```

Answer (score 1):

The `aggregate()` approach is pretty concise.
Removing bad rows

```
good <- do.call(c, aggregate(Age ~ ID, x, function(z) c(z[1], diff(z)) > 0)$Age)

x[good,]
#    ID Visit Age
# 1   A     1  14
# 2   A     2  28
# 3   A     3  42
# 4   B     1  14
# 5   B     2  46
# 6   B     3  64
# 7   B     4  71
# 8   B     5  85
# 9   C     1  14
# 10  C     2  28
# 11  C     3  51
# 12  C     4  84
# 14  D     1  22
# 15  D     2  38
# 17  D     4  40
# 18  D     5  42
```

This will only highlight which groups have an inconsistency:

```
aggregate(Age ~ ID, x, function(z) all(diff(z) > 0))
#   ID   Age
# 1  A  TRUE
# 2  B  TRUE
# 3  C FALSE
# 4  D FALSE
```

Comment: I believe OP wants to not only flag inconsistencies, but also remove the "error rows".

Comment: @MauritsEvers: I was a bit unsure about that. He didn't specify whether e.g. the 84 or the 66 should be removed, either would make the series consistent.

Comment: I see your point. I understood OP wanting to compare `Age` in row `i` with `i+1`, then remove `i+1` if not increasing. Removing `i` instead would then mean that you'd need to check that `i+1` is larger than `i-1`, and so on.