# How to remove inconsistencies from dataframe (time series)

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, aggregate

Let's say that we have this dataframe:

```
x<- as.data.frame(cbind(c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D","D"),
                        c(1,2,3,1,2,3,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5),
                        c(10,12.5,15,2,3.4,5.7,8,9.5,1,5.6,8.9,10,11,2,3.4,6,8,10.5),
                        c(1,3,4,1,2,3,4,3,2,2,3,5,2,3,5,4,5,5)))
colnames(x)<- c("ID", "Visit", "Time", "State")
```

Column `ID` indicates subject ID.

Column `Visit` indicates a series of visits

Column `Time` indicates the time that has passed to reach a certain "State"

Column `State` indicates severity of a certain disease, where 5 means death. That means that you can fluctuate from worse states to better states, but you can never improve from category 5, since you are dead.

I would like to identify only those subjects that improved from category 5 to a better one, since these are errors from the dataframe (i.e. rows 13 and 16).

Additionally, I would like to remove those rows where a subject seems to have died more than once (i.e. row 18).

I made a similar question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47723890/check-time-series-incongruencies), but it was very general and it implied that all fluctuations to a better state were removed from the dataset, which it is not what I actually want.

Comment: does this solved your issue?

Comment: No, this code is not solving the issue. It is highlighting the first time an individual reaches state 5 and it is not followed by another 5. This is not what I really need. I need to highlight the "impossible" improvement once a subject has died (State = 5) (i.e. rows 13 and 16). In my case, my data is not even ordered, so I would have to take into account the variable "Time", too. What I need is a data.frame just without rows 13 and 16.

Comment: How can `State=5` (Death) be followed by another `State=5`? This seems to happen for `ID=D`, and according to your explanation suggests the same subject dying twice. More importantly, can you please provide your expected output for the sample data?

Comment: Hi @maurits-evers. You are right. The accepted code solved the most difficult part of the problem, but we still have to remove the subjects that have died more than once, like subject D as you state. I did not explain that part of the problem. Sorry for that. The actual rows that should be removed are 13, 16 and 18. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: This has been solved then by @Uwe's answer?

Comment: He solved what I was asking initially. This code does not remove the subjects that have died multiple times (i.e. row 18) though. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Yatrosin Please take a look at my solution below.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are now requesting that all rows are considered erroneous which appear after the first occurrence of State 5 (death). This includes false recoveries (as in rows 13 and 16) as well as "duplicated deaths" (as in rows 17 and 18). This should have been posted as a new question because answers require a complete different approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer to modified question

The OP has modified the question substantially by requesting that all rows are considered erroneous which appear after the first occurrence of State 5 (death). This includes false recoveries (as in rows 13 and 16) as well as "duplicated deaths" (as in rows 17 and 18).

An answer to this requires a complete different approach. One possibility is to use a *non-equi join*:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[x[, first(Visit[State == 5]), by = ID], on = .(ID, Visit > V1), error := TRUE][]
```

> ```
>     ID Visit Time State error
>  1:  A     1 10.0     1    NA
>  2:  A     2 12.5     3    NA
>  3:  A     3 15.0     4    NA
>  4:  B     1  2.0     1    NA
>  5:  B     2  3.4     2    NA
>  6:  B     3  5.7     3    NA
>  7:  B     2  8.0     4    NA
>  8:  B     3  9.5     3    NA
>  9:  C     1  1.0     2    NA
> 10:  C     2  5.6     2    NA
> 11:  C     3  8.9     3    NA
> 12:  C     4 10.0     5    NA
> 13:  C     5 11.0     2  TRUE
> 14:  D     1  2.0     3    NA
> 15:  D     2  3.4     5    NA
> 16:  D     3  6.0     4  TRUE
> 17:  D     4  8.0     5  TRUE
> 18:  D     5 10.5     5  TRUE
> ```

The number of the first visit with State 5 is returned by

```
x[, first(Visit[State == 5]), by = ID]
```

> ```
>    ID V1
> 1:  C  4
> 2:  D  2
> ```

In the subsequent *non-equi join* only those rows are marked which appear after the first State 5 event.

#### Data

```
x <- data.frame(
  ID = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D","D"),
  Visit = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5),
  Time = c(10,12.5,15,2,3.4,5.7,8,9.5,1,5.6,8.9,10,11,2,3.4,6,8,10.5),
  State = c(1,3,4,1,2,3,4,3,2,2,3,5,2,3,5,4,5,5))
```

Comment: Dear @uwe, thank you very much for your help. This answer solves both issues. Sorry for not having added the additional requirements as a new post. Best, Yatrosin

Answer (score 2):

#### Answer to the original question

The OP has requested to identify errors in the data frame where State 5 is followed by any State < 5 for each ID. In the sample data set rows 13 and 16 should be marked.

The [answer of Hardik gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47746783/3817004) points in the right direction but does not return the expected result. So, rows 12 and 15 are marked instead of rows 13 and 16. Furthermore, there is a false alarm set for row 17.

There are three essential changes required: (1) use `lag` instead of `lead` and (2) supply a `fill` value to `shift()`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[, error := State < 5 & shift(State, fill = 0) == 5, by = ID][]
```

> ```
>     ID Visit Time State error
>  1:  A     1 10.0     1 FALSE
>  2:  A     2 12.5     3 FALSE
>  3:  A     3 15.0     4 FALSE
>  4:  B     1  2.0     1 FALSE
>  5:  B     2  3.4     2 FALSE
>  6:  B     3  5.7     3 FALSE
>  7:  B     2  8.0     4 FALSE
>  8:  B     3  9.5     3 FALSE
>  9:  C     1  1.0     2 FALSE
> 10:  C     2  5.6     2 FALSE
> 11:  C     3  8.9     3 FALSE
> 12:  C     4 10.0     5 FALSE
> 13:  C     5 11.0     2  TRUE
> 14:  D     1  2.0     3 FALSE
> 15:  D     2  3.4     5 FALSE
> 16:  D     3  6.0     4  TRUE
> 17:  D     4  8.0     5 FALSE
> 18:  D     5 10.5     5 FALSE
> ```

#### Data

The third change is required for creating the sample data set.

`cbind()` returns a matrix which turns all columns into the same type which is factor in this case. So, all columns consisting of numbers are treated as factor. To avoid this, the sample data set needs to be defined as:

> ```
> x <- data.frame(
>   ID = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D","D"),
>   Visit = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5),
>   Time = c(10,12.5,15,2,3.4,5.7,8,9.5,1,5.6,8.9,10,11,2,3.4,6,8,10.5),
>   State = c(1,3,4,1,2,3,4,3,2,2,3,5,2,3,5,4,5,5))
> ```

Comment: Dear @uwe. Your code solves most of my problem. I hadn't explain an additional issue. I would like to remove also those rows where a subject seems to have died more than once (i.e. row 18). Sorry for not having specified this point initially. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data.table` and `shift` like this

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[, status := ((State == 5) & (shift(State,1,"lead") != 5)), by = ID]
x
   ID Visit Time State status
1:  A     1   10     1  FALSE
2:  A     2 12.5     3  FALSE
3:  A     3   15     4  FALSE
4:  B     1    2     1  FALSE
5:  B     2  3.4     2  FALSE
6:  B     3  5.7     3  FALSE
7:  B     2    8     4  FALSE
8:  B     3  9.5     3  FALSE
9:  C     1    1     2  FALSE
10:  C     2  5.6     2  FALSE
11:  C     3  8.9     3  FALSE
12:  C     4   10     5   TRUE
13:  C     5   11     2  FALSE
14:  D     1    2     3  FALSE
15:  D     2  3.4     5   TRUE
16:  D     3    6     4  FALSE
17:  D     4    8     5   TRUE
18:  D     5 10.5     5  FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm still unclear what you'd like to do. Aren't rows `12`, `15` and `17` the erroneous ones and should be removed?

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(tmp, function(w) {
    idx <- diff(w$State) <= 0 & w$State[-length(w$State)] == 5;
    w[!idx, ];
}))
#     ID Visit Time State
#A.1   A     1   10     1
#A.2   A     2 12.5     3
#A.3   A     3   15     4
#B.4   B     1    2     1
#B.5   B     2  3.4     2
#B.7   B     2    8     4
#B.6   B     3  5.7     3
#B.8   B     3  9.5     3
#C.9   C     1    1     2
#C.10  C     2  5.6     2
#C.11  C     3  8.9     3
#C.13  C     5   11     2
#D.14  D     1    2     3
#D.16  D     3    6     4
#D.18  D     5 10.5     5
```